# Can a business owner be the signatory on a check made out to themselves?

Tags: small-business, check, self-employment, payment

I am curious as to whether a business owner can sign a check made out to them personally.

Comment: What if the owner was the only signer on the account?

Answer (score 4):

They sure can. They are two different legal entities, so why not?

You can even write a check to yourself, and then deposit it back into your own account. (Not very useful, but you can).

The tax implications are a very different question, as this might constitute taking money out of the company.

Edit: In some countries, when the business *hires* someone to work for them, it is forbidden by law to do that, unless he/she is explicitly allowed to do it in his contract. The business *owner* himself however, can always 'allow' himself to do that.

Comment: Agreed, I do it all the time.  Write check against business account, deposit into personal account.

Comment: Also note that, for larger businesses with a more formal organizational structure, the business's own policies (e.g., corporate bylaws) may prohibit this.

Comment: Writing a check to yourself had its uses. I have used it to fund opening a new account or to transfer funds quickly from one account to another.